# I got an Envrionment Error while downloading Tensorflow on Window

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, pip

I'm trying to do nlp on my own computer and I ran across a problem.

When I tried to download tensorflow package cmd tells me I have all the prerequisites except for one thing which is giving me an environment error.

Since the download isn't complete, redoing the whole process by uninstalling it is not an option. I tried manually deleting the folders and files but I can't seem to purge the cache.

I tried `pip install --no-cache-dir` but this is also giving me the same error.

I found it in stack overflow that there is a way to maneuver and download the package where the path is shorter, but I'm not sure if this is the right thing to do as it is quite cumbersome & other packages were downloaded fine (it's just tensorflow!)

I tried checking my system path but it is set right to where all the other part of tensorflow package is saved.

Any tip is welcomed!

[my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etd0B.png)

Comment: you might consider using [conda,](https://www.anaconda.com/) if no solution can be found.

Comment: Or you can also use pip environments. Have a look [here.](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/)

Comment: @даршан thanks for the comment!